# Development of an adaptive scale

Tags: measurement, item-response-theory, scale-construction

I need your help with a problem that I noticed and I don't know the solution (I am not from statistics). In sum, I would like to create a measurement instrument that is adaptive in that respondents can self-select the interactions they had with a company and just answer their multidimensional experiences about these specific interactions. So, for example, respondent 1 interacted with these three parts of the company (let's call it touchpoints) and would answer about their experiences (multiple dimensions) regarding these three touchpoints. Respondent 2 interacted with four different touchpoints, and would then self-select them and answer about their experiences about them.

I would like to measure customer experience. But customer experience encompasses different types of responses (affective, cognitive, sensorial dimensions) across all touchpoints with an organization (here I would like respondents to self-select the touchpoints). The purpose for now is to measure the customer experience in all its complexity, and later to relate this to antecedents and consequences.

My first direction was item response theory and computerized assessment test, but a researcher I consulted said that this was probably not the direction (as these adapt to the difficulty level) and that my problem was a bit more complicated than that.

Can anyone indicate any direction, please?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Larissa.  Could you explain what the intended use or interpretation of such an "adaptive scale" would be?

Comment: Thank you! Yes. I would like to measure customer experience. But customer experience encompasses different types of responses (affective, cognitive, sensorial dimensions) across all touchpoints with an organization (here I would like respondents to self-select the touchpoints). The purpose for now is to measure the customer experience in all its complexity, and later to relate this to antecedents and consequences. Does this answer you?